# image not display in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I located my images in `App_Data` folder and `image` sub folder .and i wrote this code in view :

```
 @if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + item.Picture)))
 {
     <img  title="Click to view product detail"  src=@Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + item.Picture) />
 }
```

`item.Picture` is : path and picture name sample : `image/1.jpg`.
condition of `if` is true  [but image not show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBIGF.jpg)

Comment: Did you check the img src in your browser?  First thing I'd fix would be putting quotes around the src attribute value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `App_Data` folder is a special folder for database files and so on.Your images do definitely not belong into the `App_Data` subfolder. Put them into a folder like `images` (just outside `App_Data` folder) then
Try This:

```
@{
    var filePath=Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/images/"),item.Picture);
    var urlPath= @"/images/"+item.Picture; //where like item.Picture=@"image/1.jpg"
}

@if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    <img  title="Click to view product detail"  src='@urlPath'/>
}
```

Hopefully it's work for you.

Comment: i update my answer just change `src=@urlPath` to `src='@urlPath'`. try this.